# Commerce - Extend add to cart button functionality

Tags: commerce

Drupal novice asking for guidance.
I would like to add some functions when the user clicks the Add to Cart button, for example, close a popup window and also change the default labels (price, checkout, etc) but I don't know which files to manipulate and which functions to use(hooks).
Can anyone help me with this?